# How to minimize a fullscreen app?

Tags: unity

I would like to be able to minimize fullscreen applications using Alt-Tab, like on Windows.

It is irritating that I can't do it, because when I am playing a game and I have a message in skype, I can't read the message without quitting the game first.

Note that I don't want to kill the application, just minimize it (and show the desktop). Is there an easy way for this?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Comment: Can you give an example of an application that you're unable to effectively switch out of with Alt+Tab? Generally Alt+Tab is supposed to work, even for full-screen programs.

Comment: League of Legends running on Wine. Also I can't minimize super tux kart when it is in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at this question: [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

There are some shortcuts that may help:

- Ctrl+Super+↓ - Restore/Minimize the current window (seems to be buggy at the moment)
- Ctrl+Super+D - Show desktop; hitting it again restores the windows
- Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 0 - Minimize the current window (Ubuntu 12.04.1)
- Shift+Alt+↑ - Expo mode for all windows in the current workspace only.

Answer (score 3):

**This is application specific.** Some applications will handle <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and refuse to pass it onto the window manager, while others let it float through.

Unfortunately there isn't a good answer to this but there are options...

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1..6</kbd> should work as a combination. I don't think it's even possible for an X application to block this combo. That will get you to a TTY console and from there you can... Well you can't do all that much. But you can log in and fire off commands like:

  ```
  DISPLAY=:0 xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
  ```

  Which you game might just ignore. Anyway, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the desktop.
- On a similar idea, you could [run your game in a separate X server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3981/start-a-second-x-session-with-different-resolution-and-sound). Loading it on TTY8 would mean you could switch between desktop and game by smacking <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> respectively.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is usually supposed to work in Ubuntu for switching applications, even from a full-screen program. However, when you're running a Windows application with Wine, it does not always work. I don't have League of Legends, but the technique described in [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=648308&p=4002731#post4002731) of [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=648308) *may* help.

Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (i.e., the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key) and type in: *configure wine*

An icon for *Configure Wine* should appear in the search results. Click on it. The "Wine configuration" window will come up. Click the "Graphics" tab.

[image: screenshot of the Graphics tab in the Wine configuration window]

Check the box that says *Emulate a virtual desktop*. Unless you want your game to appear in a Window that's smaller than the whole screen, you'll probably want to fill in your current resolution for *Desktop size*. For example, if your screen is "1808p", you'd replace 800x600 with 1920x1080.

This *should* make it possible for you to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out, because this makes Wine encapsulate your game in a window. Even if the game itself doesn't like to be minimized, and even if there is a bug in Ubuntu preventing it from being minimized, this should usually work around the problem.

It might not work, though. If it doesn't, I recommend [trying other shortcuts, as Hugo Vieria suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/339362/22949), and also [the general, Wine-nonspecific method that Oli has suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/339356/22949).

Finally, the *Emulate a virtual desktop* setting will affect other Windows programs you run with Wine (if any), but you can change it (and change it back) as needed.